# UITableView get scrolling speed

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

i have table cell with images, i want them to start loading, as soon as the scrolling speed drops about a threshold

however, how can i determine the current scrolling speed of a UITableView?

i found a

```
tableView.isDecelerating
```

however i want to load images, also when scrolling is slow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is working for me (in the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback).  I load images if the velocity falls below 1000 pixels/second:

```
static double prevCallTime = 0;
static double prevCallOffset = 0;

//Simple velocity calculation
double curCallTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
double timeDelta = curCallTime - prevCallTime;
double curCallOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
double offsetDelta = curCallOffset - prevCallOffset;
double velocity = fabs(offsetDelta / timeDelta);
NSLog(@"Velocity: %f", velocity);
prevCallTime = curCallTime;
prevCallOffset = curCallOffset;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS >=5 you can get the underlying `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and then ask it's velocity

```
CGPoint velocity = [tableView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:tableView];
```

Comment: You can also experiment with `decelerationRate` as well then

Comment: thats just a property which is used for calculation the "slowdown"

Comment: Not effective. This only works while the user's finger is in contact with the screen. At all other times, the velocity is zero.